# How do I create a generic property in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics, properties

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Private _myCollection As IList(Of T)
Public Property MyProperty(Of T)() as IList(Of T)
    Get
        Return Me._myCollection 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me._myCollection = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Basically, I want to have a collection of items that may be of any type. Then, I'll be able to do something like this:

```
Dim myPropertyValue as <the type of some value>
if (MyProperty.Contains(<some value>))
    myPropertyValue = CType(MyProperty(<some value>), <the type of some value>)
```

How can I do this? Or is there a better way than using a generic type?

Comment: If you use generics, you won't have to call `CType`.

Comment: Just curious, what is the situation in which you are using this ? :)

Comment: To follow the design convention of the framework you should keep your collection properties read-only, and have you class instantiate the list object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have to create a generic class to do this

```
Public Class MyClass(Of T)
    Private _myCollection As IList(Of T)
    Public Property MyProperty() as IList(Of T)
        Get
            Return Me._myCollection 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._myCollection = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: +1  This is the first thought that came to my mind, I was not sure if its the best way

Comment: Weird. I wouldn't have thought the class had to be decorated. But I have much to learn.

Comment: A property is nothing more than get and set methods to expose a variable within a class. The variable itself is created when the class is instantiated. If you ever write Java this will become clearer since there's no properties like VB or C# have.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to convert your [whole class to a generic one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869491/254041) you could also add generic procedures to your class (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235246.aspx)):

```
Public Function GetMyProperty(Of T) As T
   ....
End Function
Public Sub SetMyProperty(value as T)
   ...
End Sub
```

But it is not as elegant as the properties.