# can I use generic types for a property

Tags: vb.net, class

I would like to create a class that would would have 2 properties a name (as type string) and a type (as any type). The idea is I could create a collection of my class so I could pass my collection of parameters

```
Public Class parameter
    Dim m_ParameterName As String
    Dim m_ParameterType As Type

    Public Property ParameterName As String
        Get
            Return m_ParameterName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_ParameterName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ParameterType() As T
        Get
            Return m_ParameterType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As T)
            m_ParameterType = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Sub New()
        m_ParameterType = Nothing
        m_ParameterName = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I would like to create an instance of the class and define the properties as so

```
Dim myParameter As New parameter
myParameter.ParameterName = "Name"
myParameter.ParameterType = String
or 
Dim myParameter As New parameter
myParameter.ParameterName = "Name"
myParameter.ParameterType = integer
or 
Dim myParameter As New parameter
myParameter.ParameterName = "Name"
myParameter.ParameterType = clsCustomClass
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `As Type`? Not sure, since VB is awful.

Comment: You're confusing having a generic class with having a class that has a member of type `System.Type`. Those are 2 completely different concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim m_ParameterName As String
Dim m_ParameterType 


Public Property ParameterType() 
    Get
        Return m_ParameterType
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value )
        m_ParameterType = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Just leave the type blank - that is like "var" in c#

another option would be use `As Object`

Comment: var is not Of type Object in C#

Comment: var in Vb.net ; Dim test = "string"

Comment: @AppDeveloper , no - I said var in c#  is like leaving the type blank in VB.Net

Comment: Wow. Didn't know about leaving the type blank. Does it really work in the strict mode?

Comment: This worked as expected. I combined it with Ark-kun's answer by adding the GetType() function like this myParameter.ParameterType = GetType(clsCustomClass).

Comment: @Ark-kun - yes you can leave the type blank in strict mode , you just have to be careful what you cast the object into.  I believe strict mode is more for type conversions

Comment: @ScottSelby I mixed up the strict and explicit modes.

Comment: Leaving the type blank just assumes type `Object`. So it's literally the same as using `As Object` and has nothing to do with generics or var, because var infers the type and this does not!

Comment: this is pretty old , thanks @karsten - you're right , like I said it's old , and I don't have to say how much I hate vb.net.  I'm only on here messing with vb questions for the rare bv contracts I pick up

Answer (score 2):

#### `You may have to create a generic class to do this`

---

**You can define class as**

```
Public Class SampleClass(Of T)
    Private m_sampleProperty As T
    Public Property SampleProperty() As T
        Get
            Return m_sampleProperty
        End Get
        Set
            m_sampleProperty = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Usage :

```
    Dim strClass As New SampleClass(Of String)()
    strClass.SampleProperty = "wohoo_string"

    Dim int32Class As SampleClass(Of Int32) = New SampleClass(Of Integer)()
    int32Class.SampleProperty = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You cannot create generic properties, because the compiler would never know what getter to use.
Suppose you have

```
Public Property SomeProperty() As T
    Get
        Console.WriteLine(GetType(T).Name)
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property
```

What would this print for `Dim a = SomeProperty` ?

2) `ParameterType` should have `Type` type.

3) You should use the `GetType()` operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tay4kywk.aspx 
For example, `parameter.Type = GetType(String)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make a generic class for that.

Try this one out.

[How do I create a generic property in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869451/how-do-i-create-a-generic-property-in-vb-net)